# code inside a Google map infobubble not work first time

Tags: infobubble

Inside a infoBubble Google map I have added a function, but the first time the infoBubble is opened, the code not work, and if I open a second infoBubble or close the first and reopen, the code work.
Please help.
This is my page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.20&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/infobubble.js"></script>
<script>
var infoBubble = new InfoBubble();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
var map;
function initialize() {   
var config = {
    el: 'map',
    lat: 40.2329,
    lon: -3.42,
    zoom: 10,
    type: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var data = [        
['Giorgio Rossi',  40.15, -3.42,  '1' ], 
['Marta Bianchi',  40.25, -3.42,  '2'],
['Carlo Verdi',    40.15, -3.62,  '3'],
['Mario Giallo',   40.25, -3.62,  '4'],    
];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(config.el), {
        zoom: config.zoom,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(config.lat, config.lon),
        mapTypeId: config.type
    });

 var markers = [];
 var i ;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {          
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i][1], data[i][2]),              
            map: map
        });           
marker.info = '<div id="'+data[i][3]+ '">'+data[i][0]+ '</div>';           
marker.html = '<div style="padding:25px"><a class="testClass" href="javascript:;" > My Friend '+data[i][3]+'</a> </div>';

google.maps.event.addListener(marker , 'click', function(){ 
    infoBubble.setContent(this.html);
    infoBubble.open(map, this);
    var prova = this.info;
    var found = $(prova).attr('id');
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infoBubble, 'domready', function ()   {           
     $(".testClass").click(function () {
     alert(found);        
    })      
}); 
});
    }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map" style="width:700px; height:500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184410) and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33356572/3092596) 
your issue is related to a bug in the `infobubble.js` code.

More specifically, the placement of the `domready` trigger was in the wrong part of the code, prior to the asynchronouse `setMap()` call, instead of *after* the infobubble elements are added to the DOM in the `onAdd()` function (which is called after the `setMap()` function).

What this means is that on your FIRST marker click, at `domready` event, the elements hadn't yet been added to the DOM - but they *were* a few milliseconds later - which is why the 2nd marker click worked.

---

I fixed the `domready` placement in `infobubble.js` and created a [pull request](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble/pull/13) which has been accepted and is now merged into the official code.

If you update your `infobubble.js` [to the latest commit](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble/tree/gh-pages/src) (use the non-minified for the moment) you'll probably see that your issue is resolved.

[Non-working JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/rh62452x/) using the old code.
[Working JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/7r96we66/) using the new code.