# google maps infobubble dynamic content not loading on first marker click

Tags: jquery, google-maps, infowindow, domready, infobubble

I'm trying to add dynamic content inside a google maps [infobubble](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble):
- one first marker click an empty infobubble appears
- on ***SECOND*** click of the marker the correct content is loaded

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416160) I'm using the `domready` event on the previously defined infobubble object to launch the function that loads the dynamic content.
...although the JS fiddle in that answer is misleading since the 'dynamic' content is actually loaded prior to `domready` using the `content` option of the `new InfoBubble()` call

I'm getting all the right signals in console that the `domready` function is being completed and the content is being correctly found on 1st marker click.

Tried:

- looked through [the infobubble.js code](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble/blob/gh-pages/src/infobubble.js) and put console.logs either side of line 1231:
  `google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'domready');`
  The results show that domready is indeed being fired PRIOR to the start of the dynamic function.
- disabling animation using the infobubble `disableAnimation: true` option - thinking that could be slowing the infobubble load after domready is called - but it didn't work
- added `setTimeout()` of up to 3 seconds but that doesn't seem to help... and that would be a poor hack anyway.

**How can I get the dynamic content to load on first click of the marker ?**

### [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/rh62452x/)

Notes:
- for the js fiddle example I'm using a `$.get()` call - since in my application I'm using moustache to load a template into the infobubble
- the example content being loaded has nothing to do with the `$.get()` call (and yes I could achieve the same without the `$.get()` call) but I'm just trying to use similar code layout + timing to my own application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the observations [in the answer by Dr.Molle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184410/google-maps-infobubble-dynamic-content-not-loading-on-first-marker-click/33185597#33185597) I've figured out the solution - which is indeed related to the placement of the `domready` event trigger in the [infobubble.js](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble/blob/gh-pages/src/infobubble.js) code.

Unfortunately it's currently located in the `updateContent_()` function, which is called by `open_()`, before `setMap()` is called - which means that `domready` is fired BEFORE the infoBubble is added to the DOM.

It's not possible to simply add the `domready` trigger after the `setMap()` call in the `open_()` function because `setMap()` is asynchronous... and the `setMap()` function doesn't have a specific callback.

However, according to the [documentation for OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#OverlayView) (which is what is being used by this plugin) the `setMap()` function calls the `onAdd()` function once AFTER `setMap()` is called with a valid map object:

> onAdd(): Implement this method to initialize the overlay DOM elements. This method is called once after setMap() is called with a valid map. At this point, panes and projection will have been initialized.

and more simply:

> In the onAdd() method, you should create DOM objects and append them as children of the panes.

Therefore we should fire the `domready` event within the `onAdd()` function, *after* the `infoBubble` is appended to the map panes:

```
/**
 * On Adding the InfoBubble to a map
 * Implementing the OverlayView interface
 */
InfoBubble.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  if (!this.bubble_) {
    this.buildDom_();
  }

  this.addEvents_();

  var panes = this.getPanes();
  if (panes) {
    panes.floatPane.appendChild(this.bubble_);
    panes.floatShadow.appendChild(this.bubbleShadow_);
  }
  google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'domready');    // infobubble has now been added to DOM so we can fire `domready`
};
```

I've created a [pull-request](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble/pull/13) for google to update the [infobubble.js code](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble/blob/gh-pages/src/infobubble.js) and fix this issue.

JS Fiddle here with updated code (see line 910 in the javascript window for new `domready` placement)
**http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/7r96we66/**

Notes:
- I've added timestamps in the jsfiddle at the old `domready` call and the correct (updated) `domready` call - you'll see them in the `console.log` - it comes to about 20ms on my system (it will vary with system speed)
- it shows that the old domready was indeed firing prior to the `infoBubble` being appended to the panes
- this gives an idea of the minimum `setTimeout` you'd need to put around any functions within a `domready` call

If you want to use the original code without the fix - and a `setTimeout` hack:   **http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/xeL7dxye/**
...you can play around with the `setTimeout` duration and see what the minimum is - I got down to around 5ms on a fast machine.  Obviously you'd have to go the *other* way in production code with this hack to cope with the slowest machines (ie you'd put the `setTimeout` duration at the maximum level you can stand - without annoyance ~150-250ms - to cover even your slowest systems).
... or you could just copy and update the [infobubble.js](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble/blob/gh-pages/src/infobubble.js) code and be done with it.

Comment: pull request #13 (https://github.com/googlemaps/js-info-bubble/pull/13) I created has now been merged into the official `infobubble.js` code which fixes this `domready` issue - so I'm marking this as the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

the issue seems to be the `open_`-method of the infobubble(which will be called in the `open`-method):

```
InfoBubble.prototype.open_ = function(opt_map, opt_anchor) {
  this.updateContent_();

  if (opt_map) {
    this.setMap(opt_map);
  }
  //............................
}
```

It first calls the method `updateContent_` (where the `domready`-event will be triggered) and then sets the `map`. But the overlay will not be added to the map until the `map`-property has been set, the content is a DocumentFragment/Node that hasn't been attached  to the document yet, so jQuery may not find it.

Possible solution:

Use the `content_`-property of the infobubble as context for the jQuery-selector, then it shouldn't matter if the content already has been attached to the document

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infoBubble,'domready',function () {

    var that=this;            
    //when we load the additional content asynchronously, 
    //make sure that it's the correct content we are loading
    var token=new Date().getTime()*Math.random();
    that.set('token',token);

    $.get('https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-_Cox6aEnSkU/UQ_B0LK4khI/AAAAAAAAAzw/4H4dsWGPgeE/s150/go-button.png', function (myImage) {
      if(that.get('token')===token){
        $(".dialog",that.content_).html('<img id="theImg" src="https://goo.gl/phmzis" />');
      }     
        })

  });
  infoBubble.open(map, marker);
});
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/aLtz76ym/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/aLtz76ym/)

Comment: thanks for the info and the solution - good spotting on the `setMap()` coming after the `domready` call - the solution works... although it does seem a bit hackish... Do you think there's any way to put the `domready` call on a function after setMap() ?

Comment: You may download the js-file, modify it and use the modied copy instead.

Comment: yes thanks - already did that - was more interested in where you think the best place for `domready` call it would be within the `open` method.  I was thinking directly within the `open` method just after the `redraw_()` call ...?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a "best place". First I was trying to observe the `map_changed`-event of the infoBubble , but this didn't work properly as well. Maybe the best solution is to implement a custom method for inserting content in the existing content.

Comment: actually this solution doesn't work if you need to use jQuery on the infobubble content - for example if you're adding a carousel or active buttons etc - since the `content_` is not actually in the dom when `domready` fires.  (Which also means it doesn't have a size - since the infowindow is sized based on content, presumably in `setMap()`)  As you rightly pointed out it's because `domready` is triggered before `setMap()` - see the solution below.